# Call jquery function when new element echoed to page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a twitter stream feeding into a webpage. Atm they just echo down the page.
What I'd like to try and do is have it so they add from the top, pushing older tweets down.
I was hoping I could use jquery to hide new tweets then prepend them to the top of the page then fade in. but how can I call the prepend function when new tweets come in?

or is there a better method?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ajax call to get the new tweets and once you have received 1 or more tweet , loop through and use the prepend , While fetching make sure you get the sorted tweet with latest on in the last and it will be prepend on the top

```
            $( "#tableId" ).prepend( "<tr><td>Tweet 1</td></tr>" );
```